# No question mark after reported question

Tags: punctuation, word-usage

I am not sure if this was asked before since I don't know if there is a specific terms for this usage.

Is it fine not to put a question mark at the end of a sentence like this?

```
He hadn't gone to toilet for a week so he told me that he could no longer 
resist and may he go now.
```

Comment: It's not a question.  The question was in the dialog between him and you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not written a question per se. *The Chicago Manual of Style* calls this an indirect question and does not use a question mark.

For example, *Martha stopped to pick up a letter from the ground and wondered if she should mail it.*

However, *Martha stopped to pick up the letter from the ground; should I mail it?, she wondered.*

Or better, *Martha wondered if she should mail the letter she picked up from the ground.*

Simply, *She asked herself why*

As your sentence is written:

**He hadn't gone to toilet in a week, so he told me that he could no longer resist and may he go now.**

Answer (score 0):

This sentence you put as a example is rather strange and has a few errors of its own, but I will answer your question, this sentence appears to be a run-on sentence if I'm correct, in this case I recommend rewriting it or removing the "and" by putting a comma or semicolon in place of it. If your looking to keep the sentence the way it is, then you will need to put a question mark as well.

It should look something like this after editing it(corrections included)

He hadn't gone to the toilet for a week, so he told me that he could no longer resist, may he go now?